When I run my Node.js backend application in VS Code's debug terminal, it doesn't hit the breakpoints I set
I am working on a Node.js backend application using TypeScript and Prisma. My goal is to debug the application using breakpoints in Visual Studio Code. I have set breakpoints in the createDebt method, but when I run the application in the debug terminal with the command npm start, the breakpoints are not hit
I tried running the application using the command npm start in the debug terminal. Below is the content of my package.json file:
{
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"start": "nodemon --exec ts-node index.ts --inspect",
"migrate": "npx prisma migrate dev",
"lint": "eslint .",
"format": "prettier --write .",
"forever-start": "forever start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log -c ts-node --transpile-only daemon index.ts",
"forever-stop": "forever stop index.ts",
"forever-restart": "forever restart index.ts",
"forever-list": "forever list"
}
}
This is my app.json file
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "deneme2",
    "slug": "deneme2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.bybrstekin.deneme2",
      "permissions": [
        "INTERNET"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "d19cb012-89ca-4d36-8f00-a8f1eca3bbf7"
      }
    }
  }
}




This is my package.json file
{
  "name": "comesandgoes-mobil",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.4.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
    "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
    "expo": "^52.0.18",
    "expo-network": "^7.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^5.0.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~4.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@types/react": "~18.3.12",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
    "expo-cli": "^6.3.10",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}


